# how + adjective + I + be + to-infinitive

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

> ***1- I can’t describe to you how surprised I was to find out I loved her***
>
> ***2- I can't describe to you how suprised I was when I found out I loved her***

I just saw the first sentence and it seemed a bit interesting to me. I would use the second one instead. Is this some kind of form that I would see often but wouldn't hear that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two sentences are almost identical in meaning. By almost identical I mean it would take additional context to warrant preferring one over the other. The first sentence focuses on the action "find out" itself. The second sentence adds focus on the timing of the action which is useful if the timing matters and is addressed in other statements before or after this one.

Comment: As for how relatively common each phrasing is in written/spoken English, I believe both are equally common in speech. Here's what Google NGrams has to say about writing: http://tiny.cc/70r55y